# Program only works whe negative numbers entered in array last

Tags: java, arrays, methods

For some reason my computePositiveSum final output for "The sum of the positive numbers" is wrong when a negative number is entered before any positive numbers. It seems like what's happening is instead of ignoring the negative numbers it subtracts it's sum from the total. So if my input was (-4,2,3) it would say the sum of positive numbers was 1. I'm not really sure what is wrong with the method.

```
/*  Description: Write a program that reads in a sequence of numbers
                (not necessary integers) from standard input until 0
                 is read, and stores them in an array. This is done
                 using iteration (choose for, while, or do while loop).
                 You may assume that there will not be more than 100 numbers.*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class Assignment2
{
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    int count=0;
    double[] num= new double[100];

    for(int i=0;i<num.length;++i)
        {
        num[i]= scan.nextDouble();
        if (num[i] == 0) {
           break;        }
        count++;
        }
                double min= findMin(num,count);
                double pos= computePositiveSum(num, count);
                int c= countNegative(num,count);
                DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0");
                DecimalFormat fmt2 = new DecimalFormat ("$0.00");

                System.out.println("The minimum number is " +fmt.format(min));
                System.out.println("The sum of the positive numbers is "+fmt2.format(pos));
                System.out.println("The total number of negative numbers is " +c);
    }//End Main



     public static double findMin(double[] num, int count)
     {
           double min = num[0];
           for(int i=1;i<count;i++){
              if(num[i] < min)
              {
                    min = num[i];
              }
                                 }
              return min;
     }//end findMin
     public static double computePositiveSum(double[] num, int count)
     {
        double pos=num[0];
        for(int i=1;i<count;i++){
            if(num[i] > 0)
            {
                pos=pos+num[i];
            }
                                }
        return pos;

    }
     public static int countNegative(double[] num, int count)
     {
         double a=num[0];
         int c=0;
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
             if(num[i] < 0)
             {

                 c++;
             }

                                  }
        return c;
      }//end countNegative


}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but you might want to remove your name and student ID from the source code when posting it online.

Comment: Why are you doing `double pos=num[0];`? What if it's negative?

Comment: Thanks for the catch Pakku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning to the actual sum `pos` the value of the first element in the array. So if the first element is **negative** it will be added to the sum (there is no check in the code to know if it's positive or not).

To fix this, initialize the sum `pos` (by the way, it is not a descriptive name) with `0`. Then iterate in the `for` loop from `0`, not from `1`.

```
public static double computePositiveSum(double[] num, int count)
{
    double pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (num[i] > 0) {
            pos = pos + num[i];
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to name your variables with a more descriptive name. I would have declared `pos` with the name `sum`. Of course this has nothing to do with the result, but is useful for people to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the first element of the array

```
 public static double computePositiveSum(double[] num) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(double d : num) {
        if(d > 0) {
            sum += d;
        }
    }
    return sum;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are doing

```
double pos = num[0];
```

then going through the remainder of the array you need to do

```
double pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if element 0 is greater than zero.